# How can I modify the screen resolution for AnyDesk?

Tags: display-resolution

I use [AnyDesk](https://anydesk.com/en/downloads/linux) in Ubuntu, but the screen is too small. Is there a way to modify the screen resolution?

Answer (score 3):

Run in a terminal:

```
xrandr --fb 1920x1080
```

Answer (score -3):

I had a similar problem on my windows machine. I was not able to resize the anydesk window on my external monitor and it occupied the whole screen without any resize option.

Workaround:

This issue is due to scaling of your os(in my case windows)

Go to display setting scale the windows to 110% or more and then you should be able to resize the anydesk window.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This answer is not helpful for users of Ubuntu because the solution is specific to Windows.  Please refer to our help page for what is [on-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help)

Comment: Isn't there an equivalent setting in Ubuntu? Seems a reasonable answer. At least it provides an explanation...